# sScrollX not working when using a blank jQuery.datatable

Tags: jquery, datatables

I have a jquery.datatable with settings

"bAutoWidth": false,
"sScrollX": "100%"

that displays perfectly fine when data is present.  However, if no data is present, the table stretches well outside of the bounds of it's parent container.  I can understand why the sScrollX would not work in the event that no data exists, but it is causing my datatable to render poorly.  Is there anything I can do to prevent this behavior?

Thank you.

**Edit**:  I have tried *fnAdjustColumnSizing()* and it only seems to work when there is data present.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Figured it out, just had to modify the css to ensure that **overflow: auto;** was set.

```
.dataTables_scroll {
    clear: both;
    overflow: auto; 
}
```